# Karbon (KOffice) user manual

Tags: kde, vector-graphics, documentation, karbon, koffice

I'm looking for the Karbon user manual or Karbon tutorials.  It seems there is absolutely no documentation whatsoever although Karbon is already pretty sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can press F1 in Karbon, it will lead you to [**this page**](http://userbase.kde.org/Karbon14) (it did not exist because Karbon14 was renamed to Karbon, but I just fixed it by adding a redirect).

There's still not much info, but I found [**this tutorial**](http://userbase.kde.org/KOffice/Tutorials/Artistic_Text_Shape) there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Yes, too bad.  Only info about the ArtisticTextShape?